# Python Flask Redirect URL with all GET parameters dynamically?

Tags: python, flask

how can I dynamically pass all of the GET parameters from one url to another via flask?
This is currently what I am doing:

```
import os
from flask import Flask,redirect
from flask import request
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect(url_for("https://myurl.com", **request.args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I can't really do it statically. What I am trying to accomplish:

```
myflaskserver:5000/page?url=google.com&header=body&identity=flash -> https://myurl.com/page?url=google.com&header=body&identity=flash
myflaskserver:5000/dance?url=dance.com&function=dancer&move=quality-> https://myurl.com/dance?url=dance.com&function=dancer&move=quality-
myflaskserver:5000/quit?host=google.com&language=english&password=test1234-> https://myurl.com/quit?host=google.com&language=english&password=test1234
```

With minimal code, without procedurally having to use if statements, or doing it statically with GET parameters for each page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way that the question is phrased, it seems that you are looking for a way to perpetuate the url parameters only.  In other words, you're not asking how to perpetuate the url page path (or "routes" in flask terminology), perhaps because you already have a strategy for that in mind.

If that assumption is incorrect, see my note near the bottom of this answer.

It also seems that you prefer passing the parameters as *url* parameters (versus passing the same data in the request header or payload).

If both these assumptions are correct, then the following approach may work for you:

Use the `query_string` method of `request`.  This method returns all the url parameters as a bytes object (meaning you probably will need to decode it to a string if you wish to join it to your new url string).

```
import os
from flask import Flask,redirect
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    request_parameters = request.query_string.decode('utf-8')
    return redirect("https://myurl.com?{0}".format(request_parameters))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Given the first url in your example...

`myflaskserver:5000/page?url=google.com&header=body&identity=flash`

...the statement `request.query_string.decode('utf-8')` would return the string `"url=google.com&header=body&identity=flash"`, which is then appended to your endpoint `"https://myurl.com?"`.

Notice `?` needs to be added to the endpoint before joining with `request.query_string`.

**Passing page paths (i.e. routes)**

This was not explicitly asked in the question, so I won't go into much detail.  But if you need to parse the route from the request, you could use `request.url_rule`, which will return everything after the domain and before the url parameters.

```
import os
from flask import Flask,redirect
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    request_parameters = request.query_string.decode('utf-8')
    route = request.url_rule
    return redirect("https://myurl.com{0}?{1}".format(route,request_parameters))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Or you could look into `flask.referrer`, which will return the referring url from the request header *if* it is available, which it sometimes isn't, such as in cross-origin scenarios of local testing.

**Sidebar**

For the information of anyone passing by this post, it may be helpful to mention why the request as written in the question will fail:

When the endpoint "https://myurl.com" of `url_for` is called, it will fail because the method expects an endpoint (or route, in flask terminology) defined by your app (versus an external endpoint with schema and domain) when called from an active request like this.